# Uncorrelatedness and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$. How are the following two statements related:

- $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, ($X$ and $Y$ are called uncorrelated)
- $E(X\mid Y)= E(X)$ a.s., (what is this case called?)

Does one imply the other, and/or are there counterexample to such implications, or are there some condition that can make one imply the other? Thanks!

---

From a deleted reply, there is an interesting statement

- $E(X\mid Y) E(Y) = E(XY)$ a.s.

I don't quite remember it correctly. Can anyone who can see it (with 10k reputation) verify that? I wonder when it is true? Any implication with the previous two statements?

Comment: Second bullet implies first (direct from the characterization of the conditional expectation). First bullet does not imply second (direct by a host of counterexamples).

Comment: Thanks! What characterization of the conditional expectation can show the second implies the first? What ideas to find counterexamples for the reverse?

Comment: Re the Edit: sorry but which DEFINITION of conditional expectation do you know/are you using?

Comment: The measure-theoretical definition and the elementary definition. In the edit, the RHS is a r.v. times a constant, the RHS is a constant, so I will change the equality to be a.s.. (BTW, I don't remember the deleted reply exactly, so I might remember wrongly)

Comment: If you know the definition, how can you believe that the "interesting formula E(X|Y)E(Y)=E(XY) a.s." holds?

Comment: I wonder when it is true. not it is always true. Not only  correct things are worth thinking.

Comment: @MichaelHardy E(X|Y) is a random variable, so a.s. makes sense.

Comment: @Tim : Correct. I was hasty that time.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$In some cases $\e(X\mid Y) \ne \e(X)$ but $\e(XY) = \e(X)\e(Y).$ The simplest example I know is this:
$$
Y = \begin{cases} +1 \\
\phantom{+}0 & \text{each with probability } 1/3, \\ -1 \end{cases} \quad \text{and } X= Y^2.
$$
In that case we have
$$
\e(X\mid Y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } Y=1 \text{ or } Y=-1, \\ 0 & \text{if } Y=0. \end{cases}
$$
But
$$
\e(XY) = 0 = \tfrac 2 3 \cdot 0 =  \e(X)\e(Y).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y),$ then for $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$to be true, $X,Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: In the second line, what does the intersection $E(X)\cap E(Y)$ mean, as it looks to be the intersection of two numbers?

Comment: Well... "for E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)to be true, X,Y have to be independent" is pure fantasy. // @upvoter Why the upvote? Are you also the upvoter of the now deleted answer?

Comment: It should conclude "...$X,Y$ have to be uncorrelated."

Comment: @Did Why is E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) for X,Y independent pure fantasy?

Comment: @Did As the author of the deleted answer, I deleted since I was totally off about the issue. I also was surprised by any upvote on it since it was wrong.

Comment: @jnh If $X,Y$ independent one can conclude the product formula, but cannot assume the product formula and conclude the two are independent.

Comment: @coffeemath You're right, it is uncorrelated.  I was wrong, will fix it now.

Comment: @coffeemath I had guessed so. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Following the answer of @Tim, let $E(X|Y)=E(X)$. By the [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) we have
   $$E(XY)=E(E(XY|Y)).$$

   But $E(E(XY|Y))=E(YE(X|Y))=E(YE(X))=E(X)E(Y)$ and so

   $$E(XY)=E(Y)E(X).$$

   As a result, we have that $X,Y$ are uncorrelated when $E(X|Y)=E(X)$.
2. Following these [notes](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eadembo/math-136/Orthogonality_note.pdf) by Prof. Amir Dembo, we can show that the
   reverse is not true in general: let $\Omega=\{-1,0,1\}$ with
   $P(\{\omega\})=\frac{1}{3}$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$. Let also
   $X(\omega)=I_{\{0\}}(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega$.

   Then $XY=0$ and so $E(XY)=0$. In addition, $E(Y)=0$ and so
   $E(XY)=0=E(X)E(Y)$, meaning that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.
   However, $E(X|Y)=X$ which is never equal to $E(X)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Did's comment "from the characterization of the conditional expectation"

$$
E[Y E(X|Y)] = E[E(XY|Y)] = E(XY)
$$
So the second implies the first.

A deleted comment said that the tower property of conditional expectation can help, but I don't know how.

How about the reverse direction?